# How to setup base url globally for Alamofire request?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

So far I create url request like this:

```
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/room/\(user)/\(password)", method: .patch)
```

and every time I create a request I have to basic url put in every request. Can I somehow declare base url as a global constant? *(here `https://httpbin.org/`)*

Comment: Why dont you write a MACRO or declare the base url in constant file ??

Comment: I assume that it might be obvious to you, but why don't you create your own wrapper class? 
class APIManager {
    static let shared = APIManager()
    
    func request(username: String, password: String) {
        Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/room/\(username)/\(password)", method: .patch)
    }
}

APIManager.shared.request(username: "username", password: "password")

Answer (score -1):

You should use a constant file with a struct like this

```
// Constants.swift
struct Api {
    static let BaseUrl = "https://httpbin.org"
}
```

Then, on your Controller you can simply use this value

```
Alamofire.request(Api.BaseUrl + "/room/\(user)/\(password)", method: .patch)
```

Comment: Why u declare struct instead of class.

Comment: @KhawarIslam the structure’s primary purpose is to encapsulate a few relatively simple data values like it. Cf https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html